# Does Jesus want an extended Family and/or Traditional Families in the World?

Tags: john, love, commandments-of-jesus, family

I have wondererd what Jesus wanted to mean with the following (**John 13:34**):

> A new commandment I give to you, that you love one another: just as I
> have loved you, you also are to love one another. (ESV)

And, I think in Ephesians (**Ephesians 3:14-15**):

> For this reason I bow my knees before the Father, from whom every
> family in heaven and on earth is named, (ESV)

there can be traced the notion that family is important; I want to know if Jesus wanted a global family of everyone equal (in economic matters) to each other or not. I would like also a concept of *to love one another* and *to love ones from one's own family*. Is it possible to trace a decrease of family (traditional families composed with few members) to a big family composed of all the inhabitants on earth, or is it that it's necessary the first one in detriment of the second, or even, if it's possible to have both kinds of families in the world.

Comment: This reads more like a sociology question than a hermeneutics question.

Comment: @Dottard - there's definitely an important question somewhere here, I've seen lots of people wrestle over whether scripture teaches that a Christian's family *in Christ* is more or less important than their biological family. Perhaps there's a better passage or route to *anchoring* it firmly in a text, though... at present the question does feel a bit vague.

Comment: If you know such a verse, I can implement in my question.

Comment: Do you mean something like Matt 12:49?  There have been other questions about this verse.

Answer (score 2):

#### Does Jesus want an extended Family and/or Traditional Families in the World?

Through the study of the Bible, we have come to understand where we come from:

> Further, God blessed them, and God said to them: “**Be fruitful and become many**, fill the earth and subdue it, and have in subjection the fish of the sea and the flying creatures of the heavens and every living creature that is moving on the earth.” - Genesis 1:28 [bold mine]

> **With you is the source of life**; By your light we can see light - Psalm 36:9 [bold mine]

> And **he made out of one man every nation of men to dwell on the entire surface of the earth**, and he decreed the appointed times and the set limits of where men would dwell, - Acts 17:26 [bold mine]

Jesus' words in John 13:34 mentions "love" three times. The Greek word used there is agapaó which is the principled love or love of actions. Here Jesus was saying that we must treat our fellow Christians as family. We do well to remember when his mother and brothers came looking for him:

> <sup>**19**</sup> Now his mother and brothers came to him, but they were unable to get near him because of the crowd. <sup>**20**</sup> So it was reported to him: “Your mother and your brothers are standing outside, wanting to see you.” <sup>**21**</sup> In reply he said to them: “My mother and my brothers are these who hear the word of God and do it.” - [Luke 8:19-21](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/42/8#study=discover&v=42:8:19-42:8:21)

In addition, the apostle Paul also spoke of taking care of our own families:

> Certainly if anyone does not provide for those who are his own, and especially for those who are members of his household, he has disowned the faith and is worse than a person without faith. - [1 Timothy 5:8](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwtsty/54/5#study=discover&v=54:5:8)

Note the question "[How does the Bible indicate the importance of the family in the Christian congregation?](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200001488#h=12-14)" in the topic "Family" from the *Insight on the Scriptures*:

> In the Christian congregation the family is recognized as the basic unit of Christian society. Much space is devoted in the Christian Greek Scriptures to instructions regarding family relationship. Again the man is dignified with the headship of the family, the wife being in subjection to her husband, managing the household under his general oversight. ([1Co 11:3;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001488/22/0) [1Ti 2:11-15;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001488/22/1) [5:14](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001488/22/2)) Likening Jesus to the husband and family head over his congregational ‘wife,’ Paul admonishes husbands to exercise headship in love, and he counsels wives to respect and subject themselves to their husbands. ([Eph 5:21-33](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001488/23/0)) Children are commanded to obey their parents, and fathers particularly are charged with the responsibility of bringing up the children in the discipline and mental-regulating of Jehovah.​—[Eph 6:1-4](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001488/24/0).
>
> The man used as an overseer in the Christian congregation, if married, must exhibit high standards as a family head, presiding properly and having his children in subjection, these not being unruly or charged with debauchery, for, asks Paul: “If indeed any man does not know how to preside over his own household, how will he take care of God’s congregation?” the congregation being similar to a family. ([1Ti 3:2-5;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001488/25/0) [Tit 1:6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001488/25/1)) Wives are exhorted to love their husbands and children, to be workers at home, and to subject themselves to their own husbands.​—[Tit 2:4, 5](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200001488/26/0).

So there must be a balanced view of "family". As the head of the house, the husband should provide for the physical and spiritual needs of his fleshly family. And we all should cherish our "spiritual brothers and sisters" in the faith. We do this by helping them in times of need and supporting them spiritually.

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]

Answer (score 1):

Does Jesus want an extended Family and/or Traditional Families in the World?

By "the world" I assume that you meant the physical world.

Matthew 12:

> 46 While Jesus was still talking to the crowd, his **mother** and **brothers** stood outside, wanting to speak to him.

i.e., his biological family

> 47 Someone told him, “Your mother and brothers are standing outside, wanting to speak to you.”
>
> 48 He replied to him, “Who is my mother, and who are my brothers?” 49Pointing to his disciples, he said, “Here are my mother and my brothers. 50For whoever does the will of my **Father** in heaven is my brother and sister and mother.”

According to Jesus, Christian brethren (family) are more important than biological family.

John 13:

> 33 “**My children**, I will be with you only a little longer.

i.e., the Christian family

> You will look for me, and just as I told the Jews, so I tell you now: Where I am going, you cannot come.
>
> 34 “A new command I give you: Love one another. As I have loved you, so you must love one another. 35By this everyone will know that you are my **disciples**, if you love one another.”

Love one another within the Christian family.

Again, the Christian family is more important than the biological one.